# Visual Studio 2017: Как убрать серое меню при запуске программы на WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017: Как убрать серое меню при запуске программы на WPF?
В версии 2017 при запуске появляется серое меню, которое невозможно закрыть или переместить. Как его убрать?

Comment: Хоть скриншот бы добавили.

Comment: Внизу этого меню есть две параллельных полоски, достаточно кликнуть по ним, и меню сложится.

Answer (score 5):

При запуске WPF приложения в Debug режиме из под Visual Studio действительно появляется вот такое окно с инструментами для отладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его отображение можно отключить в настройках студии, сняв галочку `Show runtime tools in application` в разделе `Debugging -> General`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Emmanuel Отметьте, пожалуйста, данный ответ как принятый, если он решил ваш вопрос (зелёная галочка слева от ответа).